# Time complexity calculation for 3 nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, big-o

I am trying to improve my algorithm skills. I have a very simple code.

**Qs: Find all triplets (non-duplicate) that equal 0.**

I think the time complexity is O(nlogn) regardless of the nested loops (n^3). 
My reasoning is that :
Lets say that

`nums` length = 3. Then code runs 1 time. `{-1,0,-1}`.
`nums` length = 3. Then code runs 1 time. `{-1,0,1,2}` then code runs 3 times. `-1,0,1`, `01,0,2`, `-1,1,2`.

Similarly when length is `5` then code runs 6 times`[] [] [] [] [] []` and for length 7 it runs 9 times.

So  it seems like the number of triplets being considered increases by `3(n-2)` where `3<=n`. Therefore, time complexity is `n` because `3n-6` ~ `n`.

But because I have `Arrays.sort` the time complexity becomes `O(nlogn)`.

**What am I overlooking ?**

```
int[] nums = { -1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4};
List<List<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
nums = new int[] { -1, 0, 1};
Arrays.sort(nums);
HashSet<String> duplicates = new HashSet<String> ();

for (int i = 0 ; i < nums.length - 2 ; i++) { //i->0 - 3
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length - 1; j++) { // j -> 1-4
        for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) { //k ->2-5

            String sInt = nums[i] + "" + nums[j] + "" + nums[k];

            if ((nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k]) == 0 && !duplicates.contains(sInt)) {
                ArrayList<Integer> t = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
                t.add(nums[i]);
                t.add(nums[j]);
                t.add(nums[k]);
                test.add(t);
            }

            duplicates.add(sInt);
        }
    }
}

return test;
```

Comment: @Emma I have been reading about people that solved the problem. They are saying that it is n ^3 (n cubed time) because of 3 nested loops. So I assumed I am doing something wrong. But not sure what I am doing wrong.. For example ..look at this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9XPajMee1s

Comment: So I am correct about nlogn and the guy in the video is wrong ?

Comment: Trying to......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `n*(n-1)(n-2)/6` triplets, and the code inspects *each and every* one. The time complexity is `O(n^3)`. I don't see how `Arrays.sort()` is relevant here.

Comment: How did you come up with a formula for the number of brackets ?

Comment: @testdummy It is Combinatorics 101. Very simple. Try to prove it yourself (induction works).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are solving the [3Sum problem of LeetCode (15)](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/)

Your logic about N * Log N sorting is right. However your loops are running at N ^ 3, as [it's been explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237457/6553328).

The optimal solution (Order of N ^ 2) is:

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || (i > 0 && nums[i] != nums[i - 1])) {
                int lo = i + 1, hi = nums.length - 1, sum = 0 - nums[i];
                while (lo < hi) {
                    if (nums[lo] + nums[hi] == sum) {
                        res.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[lo], nums[hi]));
                        while (lo < hi && nums[lo] == nums[lo + 1])
                            lo++;
                        while (lo < hi && nums[hi] == nums[hi - 1])
                            hi--;
                        lo++;
                        hi--;
                    } else if (nums[lo] + nums[hi] < sum) {
                        lo++;
                    } else {
                        hi--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        res = []
        nums.sort()
        for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
                continue
            lo, hi = i + 1, len(nums) - 1
            while lo < hi:
                tsum = nums[i] + nums[lo] + nums[hi]
                if tsum < 0:
                    lo += 1
                if tsum > 0:
                    hi -= 1
                if tsum == 0:
                    res.append((nums[i], nums[lo], nums[hi]))
                    while lo < hi and nums[lo] == nums[lo + 1]:
                        lo += 1
                    while lo < hi and nums[hi] == nums[hi - 1]:
                        hi -= 1
                    lo += 1
                    hi -= 1
        return res
```

#### Reference

[You can usually find the most efficient solutions at this link](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)